# background upload large file on ios and android

Tags: android, ios, background, upload

Is possibile to do background upload for large files respectively for ios and/or android?

I'm evaluating two type of background upload

1) upload started when app was on foreground, then app switch to background and continue until upload completed.

2) background service scheduled each n minutes to start without user interaction and completely in background for uploading large files.

p.s. for large files I mean also a 1 hour video.

Comment: On iOS you would use a background `URLSession`

Comment: Paulw11 so you can do some check each n minutes, and starts upload/download without user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

This library for android only -
https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service  2.3K stars Apr 2020

Could find some similar GitHub library for iOS as well.

[image]

"
-Easily upload files (Multipart/Binary/FTP out of the box) in the background with progress indication notification

-upload files to a server with FTP, HTTP multipart/form-data or binary requests

-handle multiple concurrent uploads in the background, even if the device is idle (Doze mode)

-automatically retry failed uploads, with a configurable exponential backoff
possibility to automatically delete uploaded files when the upload is successful

**Apps and libraries powered by this library-**

-JIRA Cloud

-Quora

...

"